# How to send WhatsApp message using WhatsApp API only in C#(should not use any third-party API links)

Tags: c#, whatsapp

How to send WhatsApp Message using WhatsApp API only
(should not use any third-party API links  Ex: Twilio API, WART Tool WhatsApp ....)

I searched in Google but I didn't find any solution for this can you please tell me is there any way to send WhatsApp Message (without using any third-party API links)?

Comment: follow the documentation for WhatsApp business [cloud-api](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/cloud-api) by facebook.

Comment: I'm afraid this question is not specific (focused) enough for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

use this tool: https://curl.olsh.me/ and copy the code of the test-message you get on
YourMeatapp -> WhatsApp -> First steps -> send test message.
result i.e.

```
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("POST"), "https://graph.facebook.com/v14.0/[Your telephoneNumberId]/messages"))
    {
        reques]"); 

        request.Content = new StringContent("{ \"messaging_product\": \"whatsapp\", \"to\": \"[NumberToSend]\", \"type\": \"template\", \"template\": { \"name\": \"hello_world\", \"language\": { \"code\": \"en_US\" } } }");
        request.Content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json"); 

        var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
    }
}
```

replace the content between [] with your values.

If you only want to send a text message change the line requst.Content =  ... to:

```
    String whatsAppContent = "";
            whatsAppContent += "\"messaging_product\": \"whatsapp\",";
            whatsAppContent += " \"recipient_type\":\"individual\",";
            whatsAppContent += " \"to\": \"[NumberToSend]\",";
            whatsAppContent += " \"type\": \"text\",";
            whatsAppContent += " \"text\": {\"preview_url\": false,\"body\": \" " + "Your message"+ "\"}";
request.Content = new StringContent("{" + whatsAppContent + "}");
```

kind regards

Ottilie

Answer (score 0):

window.WAPI.sendmessage([number]@us,message);

```js
**window.WAPI.sendmessage([number]@us,message);;**
```

**strong text**

More example source code:
[enter link description here](https://codecanyon.net/item/whatsapp-bulk-sender-tools/34125850)